# Value of variable doesn't change

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am writing this code for a photoresistor on the arduino. I am supposed to attach servos to the photoresistor so that it will work as a moving solar panel. However, upon running the code I note that the value of variable pos (which is supposed to store the angle having max amount of light) does not change. What can I do about it?

```
int val1, val2, temp = 1000;  
int pos = 0;  

void setup() {   
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {  
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);    
  int val = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 100);  
  Serial.println(val);  
  for(int i=0; i<180; i++){  
    val1 = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 100);  
    if(val1 <= temp){  
      temp = val1;  
      pos = i;  
    }  
    delay(15);  
  }  
  Serial.println(pos);   
  delay(1000);  
}
```

Comment: if you want to find the minimum, you have to include the analogRead into your for loop. According to your description, you also have to add moving your panel into that loop. And wait much longer per step...

Answer (score 0):

As @datafiddler suggested you need to ad the analogRead into the for loop.

Some things I would change in order to have a faster and cleaner code:

- change the initialized temp to 100
- delete val2
- delete code before for loop
- longer delay in for loop

here the edited code:

```
int val = 0;
int temp = 100;  
int pos = 0;  

void setup() {   
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {  
  //move servo to pos = 0
  for(int i = 0; i < 180; i++){ 
    val = analogRead(A0)
    val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 100);  
    if(val <= temp){    //save minimum
      temp = val;  
      pos = i;           //save position
    }  
    //move servo
    delay(100);          //try out what works best with the used servo
  }  
  Serial.println(pos);   
  delay(1000);  
}
```